# Variable view might not have initialized and Variable view accessed from inner view

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I've gone through lots of post and forums but couldn't find solution. I'm developing an application with local html files inside for which I've this one main activity

```
package com.faraksoch.sagar.eroutine;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean doubleBackToExitPressed = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.image1).setVisibility((View.GONE));
            findViewById(webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    });


    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);


}
WebView webView;
public void goBack(){
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Here in line

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
```

I'm getting error of webView might not have been initialized and on line

```
findViewById(webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Variable webView is accessed from innter class which need to be declared final and thus when I change code to this

```
 final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
```

still no luck.

and my Main_activity file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.faraksoch.sagar.eroutine.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
     />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="576dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ssplash" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone help me with this, what must I do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are declaring a variable of type `WebView` within the main class, just before the `goBack()` function. In the line :

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);
```

You declare and initialize a new local variable which value is lost at the end of `onCreate`. Moreover, the argument `webView` is a class member which is not initialized in your code, this is why the compiler is warning you.

Note that in your anonymous inner class, `webView` refers to the class member, not for the local variable, so you have to initialize it properly and make it `final`.

Comment: How should I make it final. Where should I put what code to make it final then??

Answer (score 0):

[`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) takes an integer, in your line,

> WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);

What is the `webView` where have you initialized this variable, you should have initialized like `int webView= R.id.webView;`

You are doing the same mistale here `findViewById(webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Initialize the webview like `WebView webView = (WebView )findViewById(R.id.your_web_view);` and then use it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a major leak Everyone. I'm new to Coding and all that...for now I've only managed to develop one applicaton with help of forums and bloggers post. It would be impressive if you could comment what my code should look like. I would really appreciate and I could learn so much again.

Comment: In your `activity_main` XML there should be WebView so set an id for that like `android:id=@+id/myWebView` and now use this `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);`

Comment: sorry I have not included my main_activity.xml file...Now I have edite my question. As I have declared id already, isn't that supposed to work??

Comment: @SagarRawal - `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);` change to this `WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);`